# Turn a string into an array using PHP

Tags: php, session

My session variables are

```
$_SESSION["listofIds"]=163,164;
$_SESSION["listofVals"]=4,3;
```

I want to select session values like

```
$_SESSION["listofIds"][0]=163;
$_SESSION["listofIds"][1]=164; 
$_SESSION["listofVals"][0]=4;
$_SESSION["listofVals"][1]=3;
```

I tried

```
echo $_SESSION["listofIds"][0];
```

then it prints '1' i.e. first character. How can I handle this?

Also how can I get 1st element of `$_SESSION["listofIds"]` and 1st element of `$_SESSION["listofVals"]` after placing in while loop for mysql query.

Comment: The mysql-part of your question makes no sense to me. What exactly more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session variables seem to be strings. Use

```
$IdsArr = explode(",", $_SESSION["listofIds"]);
echo $IdsArr[0];
```

With [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) splitting the string by "," to an array.

Comment: please see my edited question in that I require these values for mysql query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$listofIds = array();
$listofIds = explode(",",$_SESSION["listofIds"]);
```

now you can access the variables using listofIds[0] or listofIds[1].

Comment: please see my edited question in that I require these values for mysql query.

Comment: Ok I got solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should start by defining from scratch an array while placing values in the `$_SESSION` array. This is a better way to write code.

Anyway as all the other answers said:

```
$listofIds = array();
$listofIds = explode(",",$_SESSION["listofIds"]);
```

will convert your string into an array and you will be able to access each value in different ways. Most commons:

- using a foreach loop
- getting the index of the item you want to use.

If you want to use the first item in a query you should get its value using the index (array starts from 0) so your value will be $listofids[0]. The same logic will apply to the other $_SESSION value.
Another good practice for programming: when you put an array value in a query string assign it to a variable before:

```
$id_to_search = $listofids[0];
```

and then use it into the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id='$id'";
```

This will save you a lot of headache with singe and double quotes.